# How to insert value into a text field through modal "pop up" window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know if this is even possible, and I'm not sure how to exactly phrase the title.

I have a simple HTML text field . On the right side of the text field, I have a "search item" button. When I click on the button, I want a modal window to pop up via jquery. In that modal window, I have many images. Each image has a specific value, e.g. img1, img2, img3 and so on.

What I am trying to do is when an image is clicked, the modal window should close, and the value of the image should be inserted into the HTML text field.

Is this even possible? If yes, how exactly can this be done? Can anyone refer me to some websites or give me potential searching keywords, or even better, a simple example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not only possible, it's fairly simple, here's an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/E23NM/1/) of how to do something similar ?

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for this awesome script! It is exactly what I was looking for. Didn't think it was that simple. One more thing though. Will your script still work if I were to insert a "tab-box" in the modal window? So I can categorize the images:

e.g.:

Tab 1 - Cats: cat-img1, cat-img2, cat-img3
Tab 2 - Dogs: dog-img1, dog-img2, dog-img3

Thanks again :)

Comment: It's just a quick example I whipped up, but yes, the principle will be the same no matter what you add to the modal, just get the relevant data and set the input box's value to that data etc..

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a lit adeneo!

Comment: Hey, I copied and pasted the code as on fiddle and tried to run it but for some reason it won't work...i added <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> and wrapped the JS code in $(document).ready(function(){ ***ur code*** }; but it wont work...

Comment: My bad, my bad. When copying the code from fiddle, a "space" character was copied that was invisible to my editor that caused the script to not run. Everything works fine :)

Answer (score 0):

the initial dialog setup.

```
$('#element').dialog({
  'autoOpen' : false,
  'modal' : true
});
```

When you click the Search Icon, open the modal window.

```
$('#searchIcon').click(function(){
  $('#element').dialog('open');
});
```

I'm making the assumption that the images are in the container we just set as the MODAL element.

```
$(document).on('click', '#element img', function(){
  //how does each image have a value? value is not a property of <img>
  $('input').html($(this).prop('rel'));
  //assumed in the above the value is stored in the rel property
  $('#element').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is very much possible. Here's a [demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/enDig) using [jQuery UI Dialog widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog). Hope that helps!

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the example. It is exactly what I was looking for. I will try to play around with it :)

Comment: Doesn't work.
console errors: `jquery-ui.min.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined`